# log4net gives build errors under release mode and not in debug mode in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, log4net

I have incorporated log4net for logging in my WinForms solution.The .NET framework being used is .NET 4.5
When I try to build the application in **Debug** mode, the log is created and the application successfully compiles but when i compile the app under **Release** modem it gives me the below mentioned error.

> The type or namespace name 'log4net' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

TO get the application working for the time being, I had to copy the **log4net.dll** under the "**Release**" folder.

I have copied the implementation from the [mentioned](https://stackify.com/log4net-guide-dotnet-logging/) link

Can someone suggest what is going wrong here?

> NOTE: Nuget was not working for me so I added the dll into my project
>   after downloading it manually

Comment: With adding you mean referencing the file? Which version did you download?

Comment: How did you add the DLL? Did you add a reference under the project or you just copied it there? What were the exact steps?

Comment: I added it as a reference. :) IT shows up under References tab

Comment: What folder is the .dll installed in?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Seems that after manually adding the reference and post build, it goes to the debug folder?